# Fill zero for missing month

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display zero on missing month, but didn't succeed.

Table:

```
clicks | impressions | ctr | position | month | year

  111       2709            4      20          3         2015
  101       2695            3      20          6         2015
  76        2714            2      21          7         2015
  .
  .
  .
  64        1212            4      25          11        2015
  81        1905            4      24          12        2015
```

Required output:

```
clicks | impressions | ctr | position | month | year

   0          0             0       0           1       2015
   0          0             0       0           2       2015
  111       2709            4       20          3       2015
   0          0             0       0           4       2015
   0          0             0       0           5       2015
  101       2695            3       20          6       2015
   .
   .
   .
   64       1212            4       25          11      2015
   81       1905            4       24          12      2015
```

Comment: You could have a help table, with all posible month numbers, do LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Like @jarlh suggested ,you can do it like this: creating a 'table' that contains all month availabe(you will have to populate it your self, add which month and years you want) and then left join to the original table and when value not exists, put 0.

```
select coalese(s.clicks,0) as clicks,
       coalese(s.impressions ,0) as impressions,
       coalese(s.ctr ,0) as ctr ,
       coalese(s.position ,0) as position ,
       t.month,
       t.year
from(
    SELECT 1 as month_num,2015 as year_num
    union SELECT 2,2015
    union select 3,2015
    union select 4,2015 ....) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable s
ON(t.month_num = s.month and t.year_num = s.year)
```